# Is an email is Spam or Ham?

Tags: code-golf

## Challenge

Given an email in plain text format, including headers, decide if the email is either spam or ham, and output SPAM or HAM respectively.  The emails will be given below. Your code **must** be able to correctly identify all of the samples, but should be general enough to work on any email.

## Scoring

This is a code golf, so shortest code wins.

## Restrictions

Do not:

- Rely on message length
- Rely on particular senders, recipients, dates, or subjects

## Data

#### Spam

```
Subject:   favorable offer
From:   "Simon Nicolas" uopt@pictishbeast.net
Date:   Sun, August 28, 2005 0:00
To:   "UK resident"

Hello! I am Simon Nicolas, a general manager of international company IFSD Inc. (
http://www.ifsd-company.com ) and I have a favorable offer for you.



Now it is a little about our company. We are engaged the organization of plans of
reception of payments for private persons and the companies. Our services

are demanded by those who has requirement to accept remittances from clients in
other countries.



Our company conducts wide international activity; we work with the organizations and
private persons from the various countries worldwide. Our activity

constantly extends, we enter new services, we expand staff of employees we open
representations of the company in the territory of the various countries.



In connection with constant expansion of our international activity we feel
necessity of new employees in the territories of the various countries. Now we

have announced a set of employees on a post "the Regional Financial Manager".



Working on this post, our colleagues produce work with the bank transfers and the
checks. Our clients are private persons and the companies of the

different countries and for simplification of remittances we use our Regional
Financial managers.

The functions of the Regional Financial Manager:

-reception of bank payments on a bank account

The scheme of work is those: the Regional Financial Manager receives money resources
and informs us on this. We in turn at once enroll the necessary sum on

the account of our client. It allows you to save a lot of time - now the client does
not need to wait for reception of money from abroad. As such scheme

allows you to save money. From the sum of each transaction lead through you our
company pays 5 %.



The basic requirements:

-age of 21-60 years

-access to the Internet, e-mail

-opportunity to work not less than 3 hours per day



It is your really favorably chance to earn!

Start to work right now! For the beginning with us you need to fill works only
labour agreement



---

Best regards,

Simon Nicolas.



http://www.ifsd-company.com
```

#### Spam

```
From: "Met Investment Fund" nclpbruehue@dancy.com
To: "UK competitor"
Subject: Job offer from http://www.metinvf.com
Date: Sat, 19 Mar 2005 00:10:07 +0000

Vacancies

We have some vacancies right now, here they are:



Financial manager:

JOB DESCRIPTION



Requirements:

Resident of the United Kingdom
Knowledge of Microsoft Word and Microsoft Excel;
Home Computer with e-mail account and ability to check your e-mail box at least
twice a day;
1-3 hours free during the week;
Be fast in decisions;
To manage MIF financial affairs through the provision of efficient and effective
financial
systems and support;
To ensure that the financial affairs are conducted in compliance with current
legislative
requirements and in line with requirements set by DCAL, DFP and DCMS;
To ensure adherence to all internal and external audit requirements;
To recieve MIF payments and our sub-companies payments and send them directly to our
investors;
To co-ordinate and control the completion of all necessary payments to our clients
(through
our site's member zone);
Have a university degree;
UK Bank account (for wire transfers from our company and our clients);


All offers here:
http://www.metinvf.com/careers.html
```

#### Ham

```
From: "Tony McAdams" <tony@mcadams.com>
To: "Bobby" <bobby@mcadams.com>
Subject: Bobby, check out this job posting
Date: Sun, 30 May 2005 03:50:02 +0000

Hey Bob,

I heard you were looking for work, so I figured I'd pass along this job
offer.  A friend of mine works for Webdings Inc., and he mentioned they
are hiring.

Their site is: http://www.webdings.com

Anyways, how's the new apartment?  Get everything moved in alright? We
should be by Tuesday with some food and a house warming present. If Tuesday
doesn't work, we can drop by any time during the week.

Unfortunately Sparky won't be able to make it, she's not really feeling
all that well. The vet called and said they'd have to keep her for
observation for at least a week. Bummer.

Anyways, I hope to hear back from you soon Bob, everyone here misses you a
lot!

Talk to you soon,
Tony
```

#### Ham

```
Subject:   Quote Selection
From:   "Simon Nicolas" simonsays@gmail.com
Date:   Mon, January 2, 2005 20:01
To:   "undisclosed-recipients"

Hello class,

Before next week's lecture, I need you all to read "His Last Bow" by
Doyle.  Pay particular attention to the following paragraphs:

    From that day they were seen no more in England. Some six
    months afterwards the Marquess of Montalva and Signor Rulli,
    his secretary, were both murdered in their rooms at the Hotel
    Escurial at Madrid. The crime was ascribed to Nihilism, and
    the murderers were never arrested. Inspector Baynes visited
    us at Baker Street with a printed description of the dark face of
    the secretary, and of the masterful features, the magnetic
    black eyes, and the tufted brows of his master. We could not
    doubt that justice, if belated, had come at last.
    "A chaotic case, my dear Watson," said Holmes over an evening
    pipe. "It will not be possible for you to present in that compact
    form which is dear to your heart. It covers two continents,
    concerns two groups of mysterious persons, and is further
    complicated by the highly respectable presence of our friend,
    Scott Eccles, whose inclusion shows me that the deceased Garcia
    had a scheming mind and a well-developed instinct of self preservation.
    It is remarkable only for the fact that amid a perfect
    jungle of possibilities we, with our worthy collaborator, the
    inspector, have kept our close hold on the essentials and so
    been guided along the crooked and winding path. Is there any
    point which is not quite clear to you?"

Thank you,
Simon
```

Comment: Are there any _objective_ (I know, overused word her) criteria for the program? As the question stands now, anything from a lame program to a real spam detecter would do.

Comment: @tomsmeding I'm not really sure how to make it more *objective* besides giving a bigger sample set. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

### J (40)

This program has a 100% success rate on the given samples.

```
echo>(+./(3#1)E.LF=1!:1[3){'HAM';'SPAM'
```

How does it work?

It checks if the mail contains three or more newlines in a row, and if so, classifies it as spam. For the test set, this holds. (Interestingly enough, from a cursory glance at my spam folder, this also holds for quite a lot of real spam.)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the syntax, but perhaps you could save a character by looking for `1-` instead?

Answer (score 1):

## Befunge 98 - 34

```
~a-!2*1-+:2`98+*j"SP"8j@,k3"MA"<H'
```

This is a translation of marinus's answer; it checks for 3 or more newlines in a row.